# How to pass a private member variable to another class?

Tags: c++

Based on my Snack.cpp, Snack header file, MiniVend header file & miniVend.cpp file, I am trying to move my Snack private member - price into my MiniVend.cpp file to generate the amount * price to return a total value of items in my machine. How do I access the price from another class?

Portion of my miniVend.cpp file

```
   double miniVend::valueOfSnacks()
    {

        return //// I don't know how to get snacks price in here? I need to access snacks & getSnackPrice. 

    }
```

miniVend header

```
   #ifndef MINIVEND
    #define MINIVEND
    #include <string>
    #include "VendSlot.h"
    #include "Snack.h"
    using std::string;

    class miniVend
    {
    public:
        miniVend(VendSlot, VendSlot, VendSlot, VendSlot, double); //constructor
        int numEmptySlots();
        double valueOfSnacks();
        //void buySnack(int);
        double getMoney();
        ~miniVend(); //desructor


    private:
        VendSlot vendslot1; //declare all the vending slots.
        VendSlot vendslot2; //declare all the vending slots.
        VendSlot vendslot3; //declare all the vending slots.
        VendSlot vendslot4; //declare all the vending slots.
        double moneyInMachine; //money in the machine

    };
    #endif // !MINIVEND
```

Snack.cpp

```
    #include "Snack.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using std::endl;
    using std::string;
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;

    Snack::Snack() //default constructor
    {
        nameOfSnack = "bottled water";
        snackPrice = 1.75;
        numOfCalories = 0;
    }

    Snack::Snack(string name, double price, int cals)
    {
        nameOfSnack = name;
        snackPrice = price;
        numOfCalories = cals;

    }

    Snack::~Snack()
    {

    }

    string Snack::getNameOfSnack()
    {
        return nameOfSnack;
    }

    double Snack::getSnackPrice()
    {
        return snackPrice;
    }

    int Snack::getNumOfCalories()
    {
        return numOfCalories;
    }

Snack.h file 
#ifndef SNACK_CPP
#define SNACK_CPP
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Snack
{
private:
    string nameOfSnack;
    double snackPrice;
    int numOfCalories;

public:
    Snack(); //default constructor
    Snack(string name, double price, int cals); //overload constructor
    ~Snack(); //destructor

              //Accessor functions

    string getNameOfSnack(); //returns name of snack
    double getSnackPrice(); //returns the price of the snack
    int getNumOfCalories(); //returns number of calories of snack
};



#endif // !SNACK_CPP
```

Comment: You call `getSnackPrice()` on the snack... obviously?

Comment: I need to call if from miniVend though. I need to determine total value from my miniVend class.

Comment: Return a reference of the private date but this is really BAD.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming getSnackPrice() is public, and Snack.h does exist, you should just be able to call

```
snackObject.getSnackPrice() * ammount
```

Comment: do I have to create the snackObject item in my miniVend header file?

Comment: I would probably pass an array or map of snacks to the getValueOfSnacks() functions, then iterate over it. It all really depends on how you store your data in the vending machine.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is friend keyword. Define the

```
  friend class className;
```

Comment: Unfortunately we have not covered inheritance yet, so I can't use it :( that would be 100x easier.

Comment: You can use proxy class like:   ClassName * VariableName = reinterpret_cast<ClassName *> &PrivateVariableClass; In this way you can acces the private variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you don't just implement `get()`? Accessing private data is really bad. You are breaking the encapsulation. But if you really want to know (i.e. you should NOT do it, it is really BAD), then you just return a reference to a private data as shown below

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : x(a) {}
    int &getPrivateDataBAD() { return x; }
    void print() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
private:
    int x;
};

class B
{
public:
    void print(int &s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A obj(2);
    B bObj;
    bObj.print( obj.getPrivateDataBAD() );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean implement a get function in VendSlot to move the snack price there?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't take a look at the code. I am merely answering the title. What I'm saying is if you want to get the private data of a class A, then implement a member function `get()` that returns the value of the private data, `A obj; x = obj.get();`

Comment: No worries - I do have a get function, however I need to get access to that get function from another class entirely.